# drag and drop for panel extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel

i'm using extjs drag working correctly but drop not working here is my code

```
draggable : {
    insertProxy : false,
    moveOnDrag: true,
    onDrag : function(e) {
        var pel = this.proxy.getEl();
        this.x = pel.getLeft(true);
        this.y = pel.getTop(true);

        var s = this.panel.getEl().shadow;
        if (s) {
            s.realign(this.x, this.y, pel.getWidth(), pel
                            .getHeight());
        }
    },
    endDrag: function(e) {
        Ext.panel.DD.prototype.endDrag.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('dragend');
    },
},
```

hint : i'm using generic panel that's mean same panel with content generated many times :)

Comment: Explain 'not working'. Do you get the `dragend` log? Have you defined a drop zone?

Comment: yea i got dragend in console and how to add drop zone for generic panel without select it via itemId or id

Comment: OK. So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: it's dragged right but not dropped

Comment: here's example  http://i45.tinypic.com/2ccotpj.png i'm selecting two panels when i'll move one ineasted of other it's will move okay but not drop check pictures now fax appear and other one hide not dropped in fax place http://i45.tinypic.com/25rk1mb.png

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. Perhaps others will be able to...